# How can I decide dynamically the base path of my templates in Angular 2?

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, constants, angular

Say I have two versions of each template, how can I define the base path of them dinamically so I can use one or the other through configuration?

Basically how do I declare `TEMPLATES_PATH` so it can be used like this:

component.ts

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: TEMPLATES_PATH + 'template1.html';
})
```

I tried declaring a constant in my root file but when I import it, it doesn't have a value, maybe I'm importing it or declaring it wrong?

root.ts

`export const TEMPLATES_PATH = './somepath/'`

component.ts

`import {TEMPLATES_PATH} from "../../boot";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a dedicated file for constants and import it.

I made a test and it works for me with your (constant creation and import).

I think that your problem comes from a circular dependency between modules. The root module imports the component module which imports the root module.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Yea, moving it to a different file other than boot, makes it work just fine, thank you good Sr! Now, if you could just tell me why, I'll mark your answer as accepted. =)

Comment: You're welcome! I think about a circular dependency between modules ;-) The root module imports the component module which imports the root module...